# Split UK postcode into two main parts using java

Tags: java, regex, postal-code

This regular expression for validating postcodes works perfect

```
^([Gg][Ii][Rr] 0[Aa]{2})|((([A-Za-z][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]{1,2})|(([A-Za-z][0-9][A-Za-z])|([A-Za-z][A-Ha-hJ-Yj-y][0-9]?[A-Za-z])))) {0,1}[0-9][A-Za-z]{2})$
```

but I want to split the postcodes to retrieve the individual parts of the postcode using java.

How can this be done in java?

Comment: Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UK_Postcodes#Format ... this is going to be a hell of a regex plus the rules may change. What do you need this for?

Comment: I need it for search box where a user can enter a postcode. I'm mainly interested in the first part so entering only the first part or a full valid postcode satisfies the use case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the official regexes for matching UK postcodes:

http://interim.cabinetoffice.gov.uk/media/291370/bs7666-v2-0-xsd-PostCodeType.htm

If you want to split a found postcode into it's two parts, isn't it simply a question of splitting on whitespace? A UK postcode's two parts are just separated by a space, right? In java this would be:

```
String[] fields = postcode.split("\\s");
```

where postcode is a validated postcode and fields[] will be an array of length 2 containing the first and second parts.

**Edit:** If this is to validate user input, and you want to validate the first part, your regex would be:

```
Pattern firstPart = Pattern.compile("[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9R][0-9A-Z]?");
```

To validate the second part it is:

```
Pattern secondPart = Pattern.compile("[0-9][A-Z-[CIKMOV]]{2}");
```

Comment: I think he's asking about the case when it's not separated by a space. The rules to do it in that case seem fairly complicated.

Comment: @Pekka - a postcode with no space will fail validation. Perhaps I misunderstand, but I though the OP wanted to split validated addresses?

Comment: @Richard yeah, the OP needs to clarify. Check out the Wikipedia link above, maybe he needs *all* separate components.

Comment: I just need the two main parts but want to cover for cases where spaces have not being entered which is handled by the above regex for validation

Comment: In that case, without looking at this more closely for a more elegant approach, you may have to check 7 different regex matches for each postcode.

Comment: @Farouk: i have added the two regexes for matching the first and second parts of a postcode

Comment: As second parts seems to be always `9AA`, OP should to remove spaces and last three characters.

Comment: @Richard H The URL in this answer is broken. I think this is the same document.  http://developer.k-int.com/svn/default/ispp/docs/schemas/bs7666-v2-0.xsd

Answer (score 1):

I realise that it's rather a long time since this question was asked, but I had the same requirement and thought that I'd post my solution in case it helps someone out there :

```
const string matchString = @"^(?<Primary>([A-Z]{1,2}[0-9]{1,2}[A-Z]?))(?<Secondary>([0-9]{1}[A-Z]{2}))$";

var regEx = new Regex(matchString);
var match = regEx.Match(Postcode);

var postcodePrimary = match.Groups["Primary"];
var postcodeSecondary = match.Groups["Secondary"];
```

This doesn't validate the postcode, but it does split it into 2 parts if no space has been entered between them.

Comment: You can stick an optional whitespace in between the two groups, then it will match with or without a space and split into two parts. I am unsure how to do that in this flavour of regex but normally something like /s?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Google's recentlly open sourced library for this. http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/

Comment: That library only seems to do phone numbers. There's nothing to do with UK postcodes on that page